# C++ shell command prompting for password

Tags: c++, shell

I am trying to call some shell commands via a very small C++ program.

Commands such as "git clone" or "rsync", which require a password. 
For example, since git uses SSH, which is interactive, I cannot supply the password to it.

My program so far is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string ExecuteShellCommand(const std::string& cmd) 
{  
  FILE* pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

  if (!pipe) 
    return std::string("ERROR");

  char buffer[128];
  std::string result = "";

  while(!feof(pipe)) 
  {
    if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
      result += buffer;
  }

  pclose(pipe);
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  ExecuteShellCommand("git clone ssh://someurl/somerepo.git");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory

**Is there a way for the process to prompt for password just like it would if I would execute the command straight from the command prompt?**

Thank you!

**EDIT:** Ideally I would either do it in Python or Shell directly, but my program needs to read different structures in C++ (python bindings would kinda be overkill) so hence why I'm trying to do it in C++.

Comment: Consider using your shell's scripting language, like batch and sh.

Comment: @nightcracker: That was my first intention, but see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices.

First, for those that have one, you can use each program's method for working around this. For example, `git` has `GIT_ASKPASS`, and `ssh` has key-based authentication.

Second, you can use a `pty` to communicate with these programs. You can do this with a program such as `expect`, or with your own code (see the [`posix_openpt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/posix_openpt.html) command).

Comment: hummm I am looking at posix_openpt right now, and it's a bit unclear to me how I should use the file descriptor to open the new process ?

Comment: After you `fork`, `dup` the slave pty onto the child's standard input and close the master. Write the password to the master pty. The pty acts kind of like a [pipe](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/pipeforkexec.html) between the parent and child -- except it appears to the child as if it was a terminal. Python has [pty.spawn and pty.fork](http://readthedocs.org/docs/python/en/latest/library/pty.html) which does most of this for you.

Comment: I really suggest you take David's suggestion of using expect, especially in this case you should look at libexpect http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/libexpect.3.html.  It will handle all these complications for you and give you a straightforward api for communicating with the process. There are a number of issues that can come up that you might not immediately realize, such as i/o buffering.  Expect is the well-tried solution to all these problems.